# Selenium MoveToElement causing onmousemove event to be raised even when mouse is not moving?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, selenium

I am doing some testing with Selenium, and during that I noticed some odd behavior that I am not sure is intended...

It seems the MoveToElement method of the Actions class is causing a window.onmousemove event to fire over and over, even after the mouse movement has completed (which is my problem and why I am posting here, and not how onmousemove behaves when a human is interacting with the browser.)

I want the onmousemove event to fire ONLY when the mouse is actually moved, like it is supposed to.  Thanks for any help.

Here is my code.

```
Public Class Form1
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.IE
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim driver As New InternetExplorerDriver()
        driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://127.0.0.1:1337/showmouseposition.html")
        driver.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.F12)
        Dim builder As New Actions(driver)
        Dim ele As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myButton"))
        builder.MoveToElement(ele)
        builder.Perform()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**showmousepositions.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="x">
    <input type="text" id="y">
    <button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="alert('clicked btn')">Click Me!</button>

    <script>
        window.doLogging = true;
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

            event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

            // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
            // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
            // (This is to support old IE)
            if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
                eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                event.pageX = event.clientX +
                  (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
                event.pageY = event.clientY +
                  (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
            }

            // Use event.pageX / event.pageY here
            if (doLogging) {
                window.x.value = event.pageX;
                window.y.value = event.pageY;
                console.log(event.pageX + "," + event.pageY);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try build.perform() ?

```
 Public Class Form1
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium.IE
 Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button1.Click
    Dim driver As New InternetExplorerDriver()
    driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://127.0.0.1:1337/showmouseposition.html")
    driver.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.F12)
    Dim builder As New Actions(driver)
    Dim ele As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myButton"))

    builder.MoveToElement(ele).Build.Perform()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi @mahesh just added build, and onmousemove is still firing even after MoveToElement is complete.  :\

Answer (score 0):

While this is only a partial solution, I've had normal onmousemove behavior with FireFox driver.  So for my use, I can live with not being able to use IE with reliable onmousemove behavior (it actually caused a memory leak in IE when I left a Selenium IE browser open overnight that navigated to a test page which was console.logging onmousemove coordinates, and that leak was caused from just 1 call to MoveToElement, onmousemove was being called in an infinite loop, blah.)

But if anyone can help me with the IE Driver still though, I'll mark you as the answer, and would appreciate the help.  I am using the latest version of IEServerDriver.exe from Seleniums site and have IE 11 installed on Windows 10.